# js injection disturbed all my code

Tags: javascript, php

This code disturbed all my work what is this?what is cause? Any Solution? please explain.

```
<script type = 'text/javascript' id ='1qa2ws' charset='utf-8' src='http://10.226.59.6:8080/www/default/base.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great work i have done.

I asked the above question but was disappointed of getting negative vote instead of giving the solution.

So i will give the solution to all who faces this issue.

1:-view source of your browser and found.

```
<script type = 'text/javascript' id ='1qa2ws' charset='utf-8' src='http://10.226.59.6:8080/www/default/base.js'></script>
```

The http://10.226.59.6:8080 is not an external link but it is a malware or program installed in your PC that generates this link.So i uninstalled many programs and add-ons but cannot recover.

At last i do it from control panel.

1:-Go to control panel

2:-Internet option

3:Privacy

4:sites

5:-copy and past the 10.226.59.6 in the text field and press block.

Thus the ip will always gone to block list.

Same way for all disturbing ip address.

Comment: The malware is also detected.it is 3G,4G internet usb that insert such code.I am using Moblink 3g usb.

Comment: The same happened to me, I was also using mobiling 3g usb. Your trick of blocking the ip is working. Thanks. Have you reported the issue to service provider?

Comment: nope. I found this code in ANY HTTP connection from a 3g/4g provider.
and the server it resides it's of the provider.
looks more like a dormant script that could be activated one day to do nasty things but only on http connections.

Answer (score 0):

```
I found this code in ANY HTTP connection from a 3g/4g provider. and the server it
resides it's of the provider. It looks more like a dormant script
that could be activated one day to do nasty things but only on http connections.
```

Solution (in your case):

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 10.226.59.6 --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:65535
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not necessarily a virus. this code is often injected by ISP (Internet Service Provider).
you can try another ISP