# Presence of inaccessible Javascript http://10.165.197.8:9090/tlbsgui/baseline/scg.js in Wordpress site

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

My website loads very slowly. Upon checking in the Developer Tools of the browser, I saw an
[ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J133P.png). This is a call to a script at http://10.165.197.8:9090/tlbsgui/baseline/scg.js. It takes over 19 seconds before it times out. I wanted to remove it, but the problem is, I cannot trace it anywhere in the code, nor the MySQL database. Furthermore, the weird thing is it is inserted in between the Head and Body tags:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">#wpadminbar { display:none; }</style>
</head><script type = 'text/javascript' id ='1qa2ws' charset='utf-8' src='http://10.165.197.8:9090/tlbsgui/baseline/scg.js' mtid=3 mcid=10 ptid=3 pcid=10></script>
```

Is this a legitimate Javascript or am I being hacked?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The question is kind of complicated to understand, I am not familiar with the `tlbsgui/baseline/scg.js`.


But if it is WordPress, it might have to do with the plugins that were currently enabled, try to disable one-by-one until it resolves the issue.


I think this question is related with WordPress and not Javascript, and no you aren't hacked most probably, might just be that your connection to the server is very slow that's why you got a timeout.

Comment: This might be some kind of problem with your ISP, see [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1411788/my-huawei-usb-modem-inject-javascript-code-when-surfing-any-website) where someone else also found that code. Searching for the library returns only a handful of results, so this is unlikely to come from WordPress, but is injected by something else.

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684272/js-injection-disturbed-all-my-code) might help.